# Visual Studio Code Apex Replay Debugger Unsupported Java Error

Tags: vs-code, apex-debugger

I'm trying to use the Apex Replay Debugger on VSCode on an Apple MacPro (Big Sur) but get a 'Unsupported Java version'error.  I have followed all the instructions https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/getting-started/java-setup.  What am I missing, please?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot , it looks like you have Open JDK version 15 which is yet to be supported!

Use the version 11 of the Open JDK instead!

Comment: Thanks Mohith.  Trying to run before I can walk in VsCode! :)